# Syntax Error in creating javascript constructor function

Tags: javascript, prototype, function-constructor

I am trying to create a constructer function as follows in javascript. But i get the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

I am getting this when i run the following in chrome developer tools console:

```
function People () {
​this.superstar = "Michael Jackson";
}
```

Is there any syntax error in the same. If not then whats causing the error.

Comment: There's a non-printng `\u200b` in front of `this` at line two. See a red dot at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jzop5b3/).

Comment: Oh yes. Now i get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a weird invisible character there, but rewriting it works fine:

```
function People(){
    this.superstar = "Michael Jackson";
}
```

Comment: Well, just thought about it because it has happened to me before ;). Usually faster to rewrite than finding the wrong character. Now you already know for next time!

Comment: certainly. I will remember this.